# pyaudio: no sound recorded

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio

I have some problem using pyaudio.

I am working on ubuntu 18.04 using python 3.6.7, pyaudio version 0.2.11
and have the following dependencies:

- libportaudiocpp0
- portaudio19-dev
- libportaudio2-dev

Basically I am running this:

```
python
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 2048*50
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 3
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "test.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')
for i in range(0, numdevices):
  if (p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0,i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
    print("Input Device id ", i, " - ", p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name'))

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                 channels=CHANNELS,
                 rate=RATE,
                 input=True,
                 frames_per_buffer=CHUNK, input_device_index=0)

print("* recording")
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
   data = stream.read(CHUNK)
   frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

A .wav file is produced but it doesn't contain any sound.

I know my microphone (the one included in the laptop is working), I can Skype for example.

Here is the output of the script:

> ```
> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
> ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel >map
> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
> Input Device id  0  -  HDA Intel PCH: ALC3228 Analog (hw:0,0)
> Input Device id  4  -  sysdefault
> Input Device id  5  -  pulse
> Input Device id  6  -  default
> * recording
> * done recording
> ```

And here is how alsamixer see the microphone:
[image: alsamixer]
[image: alsamixer2]

Comment: same problem here!